# Definite integral: $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2+2\cos(x)}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The indefinite integral is $$\int\sqrt{2+2\cos(x)}dx=\frac{4\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}$$

However, when I plug the lower and upper bounds, I get $\frac{4\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}\Big|_{x=2\pi}=0$ and $ \frac{4\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}\Big|_{x=0}=0$.

So, $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2+2\cos(x)}\,dx$ should equal 0.

However, the correct answer is $8$.

Where am I wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\tan(x/2)$ is undefined at $x=\pi$ so when using the tangent half-angle substitution you will need to split the integral at $\pi$ and will have two improper integrals.

Comment: Two things to watch out for. The first is that $\sqrt{u^2}=|u|$. The next is that your antiderivative has singularities. I suggest you look for a simpler formula for an antiderivative. Obviously there’s a simple double angle formula application.

Comment: @eMathHelp : Do you want an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2+2\cos(x)}\ dx = \int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2(1+\cos(x))}\ dx =\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2(1+2\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})-1)}\ dx =\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{4\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})}\ dx =\int_0^{2\pi}2\mid \cos(\frac{x}{2}) \mid \ dx = 2\int_0^{\pi}\cos(\frac{x}{2}) \ dx - 2\int_\pi^{2\pi}\cos(\frac{x}{2}) \ dx = 4(\sin \frac{x}{2} \bigg|_{0}^{\pi} - \sin \frac{x}{2} \bigg|_{\pi}^{2\pi})=4(\sin \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin 0 - (\sin \pi - \sin \frac{\pi}{2}))=8$$

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the discontinuity at $x=\pi$, integrate as follows
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2+2\cos x}\ dx= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sqrt{2+2\cos x}\ dx\\ =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}2\cos\frac x2\ dx
=4\sin \frac x2\bigg|_{-\pi}^{\pi}=8
$$

Answer (score 2):

In fact $\sqrt{2+2\cos x}=2|\cos\frac x2|$. So, if $F(t)=\frac{4\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}$ then the indefinite integral is $F(t)$ for $0\leq t \leq\pi$ but $-F(t)$ for $\pi\leq t \leq 2\pi$. The definite integral is then:
$$\left. F(t)\right\rvert_0^\pi+\left. (-F(t))\right\rvert_{\pi}^{2\pi}=(4-0)+(-0-(-4))=8.$$